# How can I implement promises to deal with multiple Google Places API calls?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-places

I have an Angular.js service which retrieves a number of Place search results from the Google Places API. The service then proceeds to call a detailed place request for each result. I am trying to then pass the resulting JSON back to a controller.

I believe that due to the asynchronous nature of the API calls, the detailed results are not all returned. When I log the returned places from the ResultsActivity, I can see that not all of the results are there. I can however see on the console that the results are returned after the promise has been resolved. I have tried to implement multiple promises and $q.all(), but to no avail.

I would be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction as to how to use `$q.all` or suggest a better approach to this.

Thank you.

PlaceService:

```
// public/js/services/PlaceService.js

angular.module('Services').factory('PlaceService', ['$http', '$rootScope', '$location', '$q', function($http, $rootScope, $location, $q){

var map;
var service;
var infowindow;
var basicPlaces = [];
var places = [];

function getPlaces(lat, lng, radius){

    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var promises = [];

    function initialize(lat, lng, radius) {

        console.log('initialize');
        var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: pyrmont,
            zoom: 12
        });

        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        var request = {
            location: pyrmont,
            radius: radius,
            types: ['store']
        };

        service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService($("#results")[0]);
        service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
    }

    function callback(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                var place = results[i];
                console.log(results[i]);
                $("#results").append('<p>'+results[i].name + '\n\n</p>');
                createMarker(results[i]);
                basicPlaces.push(place);
                var defer = $q.defer();
                promises.push(defer);
                service.getDetails({
                    placeId: results[i].place_id
            }, function(place, status) {
                    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                        console.log(place);
                        places.push(place);
                        console.log(places);
                        console.log(i);
                        if (i == results.length) {
                            console.log("deferring");
                            defer.resolve(place);
                        }
                    }
                });
           }
       }
   }

   function createMarker(place) {
        var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: place.geometry.location
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent(place.name);
            infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
    }

    initialize(lat, lng, radius); 
    return $q.all(promises);
}

return {
    getPlaces
}
}]);
```

Calling the service from the ResultsActivity:

```
PlaceService.getPlaces($scope.latitude, $scope.longitude, $scope.radius).then(function(places){
    $scope.places = places; //Some detailed places are missing here
});
```

Comment: `$q.all` really should work.  That allows you to bundle multiple promises together and then execute something after they all resolve.

Comment: I did try to use `$q.all`, as it does seem like the correct approach, but I couldn't get it to work. The promises still seemed to resolve before all of the detailed request calls were completed. I am new to Angular, so I am not too experienced with promises, especially `$q.all`.

Comment: Please include your attempt of using `$q`.

Comment: @ryanyuyu - I have edited my answer to reflect my attempt of using `$q`. I'm really not sure how I should be using it. It looks as if it is resolving straight away and I'm not sure how I would pass back the places information. Thank you though.

Comment: You must not fill the `promises` array asynchronously. Try to promisify all the asynchronous functions on the lowest level, then use `all` in a `then` callback.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you. Is there any chance you could show me a simple example of where I am going wrong? I'm not sure how I could create all of the promises from outside of the asynchronous Google API callbacks?

Comment: You should create them in `then` callbacks on other promises (and `return` them there). You should create a promise directly for every asynchronous API callback.